# What's the difference between description and helpMarkDown in VSTS build task (task.json) file

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

What's the difference between the "description" and the "helpMarkDown" in VSTS build task (task.json) file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description is the description of the build task. HelpMarkDown supports markdown syntax, you can set text hyperlinks for your URL using the standard markdown link syntax. Check the example below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The description is the description that shown in the list with other tasks when you are adding/selecting a new task.

The helpMarkDown is usually for user inputs, it what the user can see when he hovers over the ‘i’ icon for help.